# NgRx - Action being dispatched multiple times when in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a project (using Angular and NgRx) in which there are two pages (two different routes) where I need data being fetched when the user goes to each page. To achieve that, there is a component that when initialized does the following:

[image: code of ngOnInit funcion]

The function `retrieveTasks(date)` dispatch the action that is causing problems.

When going to the page for the first time everything works correctly, but when going to another page and then going back to this page, the actions are being dispatched multiple times (and it adds up everytime you go back and forth to this page)

- Actions when the component is first initialized:

[image: first time component is initialized]

- Actions when the component is "re-initialized":

[image]

I'm new to Angular, to RxJS and NgRx and would like to know what am I doing wrong and what is the best approach to this.

Comment: Make sure you unsubscribe when your component is destroyed and check if the ngOnInit is executed only once.

Comment: ngrx selectors aren't automatically unsubscribed when a component is destroyed. That's why you're seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you didn't unsubscribe from your selects (observables), so they are still live even though component is destroyed

change to this

```
export class component implement OnInit, OnDestroy  {

   private unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject<Any>();

   ngOnInit() {


     this.store.select(selector)
     // add takeUntil on all selects or any other observables you subscribe
        .pipe(
           takeUnitl(this.unsuscribeAll)
        )
        .subscribe(...) //rest of your code for subscription

   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
      this.unsubscribeAll.next();
      this.unsubscribeAll.complete();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know selects didn't unsubscribe on destroy.

Comment: @BárbaraEste none of the observables will unsubscribe automatically, the only exception according to angular documentation is routing observables, also in that case it doesn't harm to unsubscribe